# Ansible repeat task until a specified string is in the output

Tags: ansible, big-ip

I have an task that needs to be executed till there is a certain string in the stdout.
The stdout of bigip_command is a list (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/bigip_command_module.html#return-values)

```
    - name: Disable pool member
      bigip_command:
        commands: "tmsh show /sys connection ss-server-addr xx.xx.xx.xx ss-server-port 8080"
        provider:
          user: "xx"
          password: "xxx"
          server_port: xx
          server: xxx
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: result
      until: "'Total records returned: 0' in result.stdout"<br><br>
```

Output is:

FAILED - RETRYING: Disable pool member (3 retries left)

But Total records returned: 0 is in the result.stdout.

with debug the output is:

```
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

output:

```
    ok: [xxx] => {
        "msg": [
            "Sys::Connections\nTotal records returned: 0"
       ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Retrying a task until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met). Try

```yaml
- name: Disable pool member
  vars:
    my_regex: 'Total records returned: 0'
  bigip_command:
    commands: "yyy"
    user: "xx"
    password: "xxx"
    server_port: xx
    server: xxx
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: result
  until: result.stdout is search(my_regex)
  retries: 5
  delay: 10
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>